# Responsive IMG to maintain both viewport size and device pixel ratio

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive

I need to use `<img>` NOT `<picture>` to deliver different image dimensions for both viewport size and device pixel ratio. 
Example (code is not valid):

```
<img srcset="store/img-200.jpg 180w, store/img-200.jpg 180w 2x">
```

Are there any workarounds for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've stopped at adding more viewport variables.

```
<img srcset="https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=400 800w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=1200&h=600 1200w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=1600&h=800 1600w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=2000&h=1000 2000w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=2400&h=1200 2400w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=2800&h=1400 2800w,
        https://myserver.com/image?w=3200&h=1600 3200w"
sizes="100vw">
```

Image will be downloaded by the browser for several configurations:

- screen density 1 with viewport width equal to or below 2400px
- screen density 2 with viewport width equal to or below 1200px
- screen density 3 with viewport width equal to or below 800px